# Showing two UFD elements are relatively prime without Bézout

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am struggling to prove a result about greatest common divisors that will lead eventually to Gauss's Lemma.

In particular, we let $R$ be a UFD with $\alpha,\beta \in R$. Define $\delta=\textrm{gcd}(\alpha,\beta)$, which exists because $R$ is a UFD. My book claims that there exist *relatively prime* elements $\alpha',\beta'\in R$ such that $\alpha=\delta\alpha'$ and $\beta = \delta \beta'$.

My problem is that I cannot show that $\textrm{gcd}(\alpha',\beta')=1$. If $R$ were a PID, this would be easy with the help of Bézout's identity. By Bézout $s\alpha +t\beta = \delta$ for some $s,t\in R$. Substitute $\alpha=\delta\alpha'$ and $\beta = \delta \beta'$ to write $s(\delta\alpha')+t(\delta\beta')=\delta$. We then cancel and find $s\alpha' +t\beta' =1$. Hence, $\gcd(\alpha',\beta')=1$ by Bézout. However, $R$ is not necessarily a PID, so I cannot use Bézout's identity.

Is there a clever/obvious way to get around this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we know that $R$ is ufd, and we don't know anything else. As such, it seems reasonable to write down the unique prime factorisations of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and see what we can do with them. I've pared that down slightly, only explicitly writing down the primes that divide both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but it's still the intuition behind the proof.

Let $p_1, \ldots, p_m$ be the distinct irreducible elements dividing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then since $R$ is a ufd, we may write 
$$
\alpha = p_1^{a_1}\ldots p_m^{a_m}x
$$
$$
\beta = p_1^{b_1}\ldots p_m^{b_m}y
$$
for $a_i, b_i \geq 1$ and $x, y$ not divisible by any of the $p_i$. Since the $p_i$ are the only irreducibles dividing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have that $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

For each $i$, let $c_i = \min({a_i, b_i})$. Then $\delta = p_1^{c_1}\ldots p_m^{c_m}$ is the greatest common divisor of $\alpha, \beta$ (I'm not sure what definition you're using of gcd, but whatever it is, it shouldn't be too hard to check that this is true).

Let $\alpha' = p_1^{a_1 - c_1}\ldots p_m^{a_m - c_m}x$ and $\beta' = p_1^{b_1 - c_1}\ldots p_m^{b_m-c_m}$. Note that $\alpha = \delta \alpha'$ and $\beta = \delta \beta'$.

Then the primes dividing $\alpha'$ are precisely the primes dividing $x$ and the $p_i$ with $a_i > b_i$. Similarly the primes dividing $\beta'$ are precisely the primes dividing $y$ and the $p_i$ with $a_i < b_i$. It is then clear that these two sets of primes are distinct, so there are no primes that divide both $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$, and hence $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are coprime.